# Textbook Recommendation for IS-LM AS-AD Models

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, textbooks

I am currently taking an intro to macroeconomics class, and I am looking for undergraduate level study material to understand the IS-LM model and its interactions with the AS-AD model. Can you give me any good recommendation? I have no problems dealing with any math intensive material. The textbook that I am reading at the moment is Macroeconomics by Olivier Blanchard.

Comment: Macroeconomics by Olivier Blanchard would have been my recommendation.

Comment: I second BB king. What exactly do you think is missing in Blanchard?

Comment: You can also watch this video (if you prefer) to understand the connection: https://youtu.be/5euKG8YclWg

Comment: @BBKing please post answers as answers

Comment: t is very difficult to answer without further details by the OP. Maybe, the OP (as they speaks of mathematics) thinks that Blanchard is unsatisfactory with regard to formalization, but it's just a guess. –

Answer (score 3):

Short opinion pieces/notes by Paul Krugman which might be interesting for the new students of macroeconomics:

1. http://web.mit.edu/krugman/www/islm.html
2. https://archive.nytimes.com/krugman.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/10/09/is-lmentary/
3. [Closed Canadian economy edition](http://www.egwald.ca/macroeconomics/basicislm.php)

Answer (score 1):

Macroeconomics by Olivier Blanchard would have been my recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read something more advanced on the topics you mentioned, I’d recommend <<Macroeconomics: Imperfections, Institutions, and Policies>> by Wendy Carlin and David Soskice

Answer (score 1):

Blanchard is a good text. I am not sure what exactly you are looking for. Most undergrad macro texts are written in a similar way. But if you want to check an alternative presentation of the material, I recommend Mankiw's Macroeconomics.
If memory serves me well, Blanchard uses a medium-run AS while Mankiw prefers to use short-run and long-run curves. It is possible that both authors present LM curves differently.